# Hacks to reduce pain due to a injection

Tags: comfort

I recently got bit by a dog. So, I am being given an injection everyday. It is causing a great pain . Are there any hacks to reduce this pain???

Comment: If they can identify and test the dog to be certain it's not rabid, you may not need to finish the series of injections.

Comment: The dog is out of reach. It happened very far away from my house.

Comment: Then your choices are to endure the pain of the injection series, or refuse treatment and risk an agonizing death from rabies.  I'd take the shots.

Comment: Ask if they can apply lidocane gel to the site first.

Answer (score 1):

Go see a competent hypnotherapist. S/he can quickly train you (using a technique called "anchoring") to make the location of the injection numb so that you will feel no pain when getting the shot.

Answer (score 1):

Chill the area to be injected with ice or an ice pack for a few minutes before the injection. A bag of frozen vegetables works well for this. Cold will dull the nerves and lessen the amount of pain felt.